# JPA method not returning results even though the generated query returns results when used in postgres console

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm not getting any results for JPA method even though when i log the query and try it on the database console i get the correct results

REPO:

public interface FireWeatherDay1CatRiskRepository extends

```
JpaRepository<FireWeatherDay1CatRisk, Long> {
    List<FireWeatherDay1CatRisk> findByAdvTs(Instant advTs);
}
```

GENERATED QUERY:

```
select fireweathe0_.id as id1_0_,
       fireweathe0_.adv_ts as adv_ts2_0_,
       fireweathe0_.category as category3_0_,
       fireweathe0_."end" as end4_0_,
       fireweathe0_.geom as geom5_0_,
       fireweathe0_.start as start6_0_
from fire_weather_day1_cat_risk fireweathe0_
    where fireweathe0_.adv_ts='2021-09-28T17:00:00Z';
```

Again, no results return when using the JPA method, but the query generated seems to be correct when i manually run the query in my postgres console it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure this JPA application is connected to the same database and schema? Are you able to use JPA to find the same rows that show up in the postgres console using a findById query in the application?

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the same query.
What JPA is executing is most certainly

```
select fireweathe0_.id as id1_0_,
       fireweathe0_.adv_ts as adv_ts2_0_,
       fireweathe0_.category as category3_0_,
       fireweathe0_."end" as end4_0_,
       fireweathe0_.geom as geom5_0_,
       fireweathe0_.start as start6_0_
from fire_weather_day1_cat_risk fireweathe0_
    where fireweathe0_.adv_ts=?;
```

plus a value for the bind value.

The problem is most likely that some conversion happens to the instant, probably involving the current timezone of your JVM or of the database.